# Cannot print GET request with long length in PHP

Tags: php, xml

```
localhost/index.php?proof_xml=%3CAuthProof%3E%3CTime%3E2018+Mar+03+16%3A42%3A06%3C%2FTime%3E%3CVEReqProof%3E%3CMessage+id%3D%22c12Wrq0yBXr3nLA2d3u1%22%3E%3CVEReq%3E%3Cversion%3E1.0.2%3C%2Fversion%3E%3CMerchant%3E%3CacqBIN%3E518670%3C%2FacqBIN%3E%3CmerID%3E5586000012131%3C%2FmerID%3E%3C%2FMerchant%3E%3CBrowser%3E%3CdeviceCategory%3E0%3C%2FdeviceCategory%3E%3Caccept%3E%2A%2F%2A%3C%2Faccept%3E%3CuserAgent%3EMozilla%2F5.0+%28X11%3B+Linux+i686%3B+rv%3A49.0%29+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F49.0+SeaMonkey%2F2.46%3C%2FuserAgent%3E%3C%2FBrowser%3E%3C%2FVEReq%3E%3C%2FMessage%3E%3C%2FVEReqProof%3E%3CVEResProof%3E%3CMessage+id%3D%22c12Wrq0yBXr3nLA2d3u1%22%3E%3CVERes%3E%3Cversion%3E1.0.2%3C%2Fversion%3E%3CCH%3E%3Cenrolled%3EY%3C%2Fenrolled%3E%3C%2FVERes%3E%3C%2FMessage%3E%3C%2FVEResProof%3E%3C%2FAuthProof%3E
```

I want it to print it as it is using a GET method. There are some more attributes as well, but I need to print proof_xml only.

```
echo $_GET['proof_xml'];
```

I want its output as:

```
%3CAuthProof%3E%3CTime%3E2018+Mar+03+16%3A42%3A06%3C%2FTime%3E%3CVEReqProof%3E%3CMessage+id%3D%22c12Wrq0yBXr3nLA2d3u1%22%3E%3CVEReq%3E%3Cversion%3E1.0.2%3C%2Fversion%3E%3CMerchant%3E%3CacqBIN%3E518670%3C%2FacqBIN%3E%3CmerID%3E5586000012131%3C%2FmerID%3E%3C%2FMerchant%3E%3CBrowser%3E%3CdeviceCategory%3E0%3C%2FdeviceCategory%3E%3Caccept%3E%2A%2F%2A%3C%2Faccept%3E%3CuserAgent%3EMozilla%2F5.0+%28X11%3B+Linux+i686%3B+rv%3A49.0%29+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F49.0+SeaMonkey%2F2.46%3C%2FuserAgent%3E%3C%2FBrowser%3E%3C%2FVEReq%3E%3C%2FMessage%3E%3C%2FVEReqProof%3E%3CVEResProof%3E%3CMessage+id%3D%22c12Wrq0yBXr3nLA2d3u1%22%3E%3CVERes%3E%3Cversion%3E1.0.2%3C%2Fversion%3E%3CCH%3E%3Cenrolled%3EY%3C%2Fenrolled%3E%3C%2FVERes%3E%3C%2FMessage%3E%3C%2FVEResProof%3E%3C%2FAuthProof%3E
```

But I'm unable to print `$_GET['proof_xml']`, its output is empty.

**Update**:
This happened because the length of GET variable was very lengthy. So I just put `suhosin.get.max_value_length = 3000` this in the php.ini file.

Comment: Using echo $_GET['proof_xml']; should do it, whats the problem?

Comment: It probably is going to encode it though

Comment: No its not working, using echo $_GET['proof_xml'];
I tried to decode and then tried to print it but it's not working at all.

Comment: See Phil's answer, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What's exactly is not working with the GET?

Comment: @James What I actually want is, to print the value of proof_xml.
Example:
 localhost/index.php?a=Welcome
`echo $_GET['a'];`
//Output:
Welcome

Comment: I get that, but you tried using GET, what happened, why did it not work?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not getting any error. That's why I'm trying to find the way. I think it's not possible to GET the XML code using GET method.

Comment: what does this show `var_dump($_GET['proof_xml']);`

Comment: I've voted to close as it's unclear what you're asking. You stated in your question you use `$_GET['proof_xml']` but haven't stated why or how that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because the length of GET variable was very lengthy. So I just put this to php.ini file `suhosin.get.max_value_length = 3000` and everything started working as how I want it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want it URL encoded, try using `urlencode`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php for more details.

Comment: Actually, the above one code is an XML code, which is encoded. But the problem is I can not print it through GET method from the given attribute.

Comment: Can you right click on your browser and see what it actually prints? in Chrome you can 'View source' and there you can see the raw output.